# center web mail IE issue

Tags: html, css, email

How can I center the panel for an email that's viewed in IE using Gmail without the inner copy being centered as well?  I'm currently using the center tag to position the entire design into the middle of the screen, although I need the copy to be left justified successfully in IE.

```
<center>
<table>
<tr>
  <td style="text-align: left;">
    This is centered as well 
  </td>
</tr>
</center>
```

Comment: @j08691 Maybe it has, but creating templates that work in all email clients requires you to code as if it were a dozen years ago.

Comment: correct, unfortunately email support across all platforms and browsers is a laugher at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

worked it out.. use center for the top panel but all copy inside that looks to work if you add text-align: left to each and every piece of copy

Answer (score 0):

Check out the mailchimp templates. http://mailchimp.com/resources/html-email-templates/

I believe you can just use the normal margin:auto; to center the table, and then nothing would be inherited.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the actual markup you are using, it could be because it is not valid. You are missing the closing `</table>` tag before closing the center tag:

```
<center>
<table>
<tr>
  <td style="text-align: left;">
    This is centered as well 
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
```

Comment: worked it out I think..  use center for the top panel but all copy inside that looks to work if you add text-align: left to each and every piece of copy

Comment: Yeah that was to be my next suggestion. Wrap the text in `<p style="text-align: left;"></p>`